# Allow restricted users to install software on Windows

Tags: windows, security, group-policy

Is there any way in Windows XP, Vista or 7, where you can set a domain user as a restricted user, but then allow to install certain approved applications?  For example, allow them to download and install updates to TweetDeck themselves?

I'm looking for a way to say "these applications are approved and you may install them if they have this name, and come from the URL, etc".

I know about using GPO to automate installs, but I don't think that is an option with TweetDeck and other Adobe Air apps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might take a look at [AppLocker](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548340(WS.10).aspx) which is a new microsoft technology intended to give this type ofcontrol over installing applications.  However, it's Windows 7 only.

Comment: This is a perfect solution...almost.  To enable AppLocker, each of our users needs to be running Windows 7 Enterprise edition (equivalent to Ultimate on the personal side).  I was so looking forward to this being the solution, but our company couldn't afford to get the licenses so we opted for Win 7 Professional instead.

Comment: wow - I didn't realize it was only available in Enterprise.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up software restriction policies. Only add certain file paths like C:\Program files\tweetdeck and all other locations tweetdeck needs to update for its install. the only problem i see is having them setup as restricted users..